# How to dynamically create kml file

Tags: ios, sqlite, mkmapview, kml

In my `iOS` application, I have 20000 records in `SQLite` database with location data city, latitude, longitude, country, state, zip and so on.How to create `KML` file with these data to apply  visual effects to map in map view ?

Comment: Have you ever managed to do this? Im using the iOS KML Framework and created a file but I'm trying to upload or export that file.

Answer (score 0):

I use this library for KML parsing: https://github.com/FLCLjp/iOS-KML-Framework. It is very full-featured, and is easily extendable.

It also has the ability to generate KML files, like you need, although I've not needed to use that yet. The KMLPlacemark class is the one you need to create placemarks for your data.

See the Google KML reference for details on the KML standard: https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference

Comment: If you use python, then pyKML is another great library.

Comment: The OP is developing for iOS, thus presumably programming in Objective-C. If they are creating the KML file offline, then Python would be an option.

Comment: If you are doing this offline I would write the code to loopthrough your 20000 records and create a Placemark for each one.

Comment: Do you really need to create KML? If you're just viewing it, create an MKAnnotation and MKAnnotationView for each record being viewed.
Query the database for lat/long within a certain bounds and create the placemark only when you need to view it. That way your app is more responsive.

Take a look at this tutorial:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/2847/introduction-to-mapkit-on-ios-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

You can make a method that will read the location data you have and then wrap those data with KML tags. For example this is the code for making a placemark :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Placemark>
    <name>Simple placemark</name>
    <description>Attached to the ground. Intelligently places itself 
       at the height of the underlying terrain.</description>
    <Point>
      <coordinates>-122.0822035425683,37.42228990140251,0</coordinates>
    </Point>`
  </Placemark>
</kml>
```

In the same way you can wrap your data to disply lines or surfaces.
Here you find more https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_tut